# Sum the entries of items with the same index ID in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that contains a variable number of sub arrays.
Each sub-array contains a list of numeric keys and values.
I have a separate array that is the result of an "array_intersect_key" function against the multidimensional array that contains only the keys that exist in each sub-array.

I want to walk through the intersect_key array and for each item in it sum the values associated with the matching keys within the multidimensional array and then take the total and use that to replace the value associated with the key in the intersect_key array while maintaining the same index id.

The key in each array relates to the id of an article in the database, the value associated with the key is how many times a certain word appears in that article. I'm trying to add together all the word counts relating to each article so I can then order them by relevance.

The code that creates the arrays:

```
$arr_articles = array();
foreach($arr_words as $wordid => $word) {
    $query = "SELECT articleid,wordcount FROM index_wordsearch AS iws WHERE iws.keywordid = '$wordid'";
    $articlesearch = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$articlesearch) {
        die('Unable to search for articles matching the specified words: '.mysql_error());
    } else {
        $arr_ids = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($articlesearch)) {
            $articleid = $row['articleid'];
            $wordcount = $row['wordcount'];
            $arr_ids["$articleid"] = "$wordcount";
        }
        $arr_aticles[] = $arr_ids;
    }
}
$arr_matches = call_user_func_array('array_intersect_key',$arr_articles);
```

I've started trying to tackle this by using the `call_user_func_array()` call again to branch out to a custom function but this approach doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe replace

```
$arr_ids["$articleid"] = "$wordcount";
```

with

```
if (!isset($arr_ids[$articleid]))
  $arr_ids[$articleid] = 0;

$arr_ids[$articleid] += $wordcount;
```

I suggest for performance, that you retrieve all required data with a single SQL query (maybe using `WHERE iws.keywordid IN (...)`) and then process results in a PHP loop. Generally speaking, putting an SQL query in a loop should be avoided.

**EDIT** suggestion:

```
$query = "SELECT articleid, SUM(wordcount) AS wordcount
  FROM index_wordsearch
  WHERE keywordid IN (".implode(", ", array_keys($arr_words)).")
  GROUP BY articleid";

$articlesearch = mysql_query($query) or die('Unable to search for articles matching the specified words: '.mysql_error());

$arr_articles = array();
 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($articlesearch))
    $arr_articles[$row['articleid']] = $row['wordcount'];

print_r($arr_articles); // shows total matched word count for each article id
```

Comment: Frosty, that wouldn't work as each sub array of `$arr_ids` is for a specific word and is an array containing a list of article ids and corresponding word counts for that word.

Comment: There is already an `$arr_words` which contains the word id and the word itself, this is the list of words that the user has searched for (the word id's are populated from a mysql query).

Comment: Oh, I missed the `$arr_words` at the `foreach` line, sorry. I remove that from my answer. But the idea of `$arr_ids[$articleid] += $wordcount;` should be still valid.

Comment: Note that you have a typo: I see `$arr_aticles[] = ...` in the loop, instead of `$arr_articles[] = ...` (*r* missing)

Comment: Frosty, yes, that typo was caused when I reformatted it for posting.

Comment: using your `$arr_ids[$articleid] += $wordcount;` idea it definitely does "something" but I'm not sure it's adding all the word counts together... For instance, if I perform a 3 word search and one of the articles contains word 1 twice and the other two words only once then it comes back with a total word count in the array of 1 when I would expect it to say 4...

Comment: Edited my answer for a more complete suggestion ; I hope it will help.

Comment: Frosty, thanks again. The SQL query isn't working `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN (9, 3, 19)' at line 1` but I should be able to work that out.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it. In fact there was `= IN` instead of `IN`. Fixed my answer :)

Comment: Closer... now I no longer have an array of arrays to run my `array_intersect_key` against to produce an array that only contains article id's that contain all the searched for words.

Comment: In fact I think that you don't need the `array_intersect_key` anymore. What do you exactly want as result in `$arr_articles` (or `$arr_matches`)?

Comment: I'm trying to find the articles that contain all the searched for words but I'll need to be able to change this soon to have words not to be included as well, in a boolean type manner.

I was originally using a fulltext search, but, with nearly 500,000 articles and each one being at least 4k with some of them being in the 1.5Mb range it quickly became unusable so I'm now creating an index of keywords...

Comment: Ok. That will be quite complex but having created the "index of keywords" table is clearly the right way to go :) I suggest you to cut down the problem in small parts (1. articles containing all the searched words, 2. articles not containing some words...) and if necessary, ask other questions on SO for those specific problems.